# Sequencing issue between viewWillAppear & viewWillDisappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am facing a strange issue:

When I am switching from one view controller to another view controller, my viewWillDisappear of first VC gets called and then viewWillAppear of second view controller gets called.

This is the correct sequence and my app behaves fine but when I share my app with some other app and present my app as a modal from that app then within my app when I do the above mentioned transition, viewWillAppear of second view controller gets called first and then viewWillDisappear of first view controller gets called. This creates a problem.

Can someone help me understanding why this different behavior? I am enabling a functionality in viewWillAppear and disabling it in viewWillDisappear, so in second case I always end up disabling the functionality.

Comment: How are you presenting your app modally from within another app?

Comment: I am sharing my app as a static lib and exposing a class which presents the starting view controller as modal on the current view controller of second app.

Comment: So, effectively, you are creating a library for the new application right? Not presenting an application from within an application I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted out by changing the sequence... Like I am enabling the Feature in viewDidAppear but disabling it in viewWillDisappear.